# Query params has no effect with Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs

I followed many tutorials to try make query parameters work with Angular2+ (using the old `Http` module, not the new `HttpClient` module)

Here is what I got:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith'; 

 getCurrentServiceMenu(till: Till) {
    const myParams = new URLSearchParams();
    myParams.set('till_uuid', till.uuid);

    return this.http.get(
      wsGetCurrentServiceMenu.url,
      {
        params: myParams,
        headers: this.authService.getAuthorizationHeader(),
      })
      .timeoutWith(timeout, Observable.throw(''));
  }
```

It makes no error, but has no effect : there is no parameter in the query.

I'm using Angular 5.0.0 with rxjs 5.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import angular's `URLSearchParams` class

```
import { Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

You are using the native javascript [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

---

Alternatively you could use the native javascript class, however you need to convert it to a string.

```
return this.http.get(
    wsGetCurrentServiceMenu.url,
    {
        params: myParams.toString(),
        headers: this.authService.getAuthorizationHeader(),
    })
    .timeoutWith(timeout, Observable.throw(''));
```

This confusion is what probably led the angular team to use [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) as a replacement in the new HttpClient

Comment: Thanks for this! Very confusing indeed :)